# android layout hide/show views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linear vertical layout as below. I need in my application to switch the Button and the TextView. To hide button and show text then change etc. If I use setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) for the button it disappears from the screen but it still hold the place. How can I switch those elements without remove them completely?

```
        <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Chronometer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stop_button" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wrongCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="" />
```

Comment: Used  `setVisibility(View.GONE)` instead  `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: try to use View.GONE it will disappear and won't hold place in your screen. cheers

Comment: You can use **setVisibility(View.GONE)**. If you use setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) means its just disappear from screen but its space will be there. So you just use Visibility **GONE** so its properly disappear with its place.

Comment: How can I show it back?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use-

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: you can set again button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Yes. I didn't know that GONE is revertible. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Suppose your created button is as follows...

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
```

When you want to hide that Button write this...

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And when you want to show that button again then write...

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should used `setVisibility(View.GONE)` instead of `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

For more information go to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html