# Add or Remove ImageView dynamically

Tags: android, imageview

Is there any way to add or remove android imageview in UI dynamically ? I have 2 objects : List view and image view. I want to show each other dynamically without crashing each other.

Comment: do you want mean you want to hide one while showing the other ?

Comment: Just a quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844933/android-layout-hide-show-views

Comment: You can try ExpandableGridView for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to show listView and hide ImageView, you can follow below code.

```
listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // showing listview

imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hiding imageview
```

you can choose which one to `show` and which one to `hide`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both loaded from xml and then keep playing with View.VISIBILITY set it to GONE to hide and VISIBLE to make it vsible again.

Answer (score 0):

So can either implement idea suggest by above.

Or for more cleaner code you can put elements in different layout and make the complete layout as visible or hidden whenever a certain event is being triggered!!

Hope this helps....!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can put listview and imageview into FrameLayout and switch visibility